# Shift, Rotate and Rotate All: What are they used for and do I need them all?

Tags: logic, cpu-registers, microprocessors, machine-code, ttl

**My question:** What exactly is the Rotate All function used for and can it be implemented another way in software if needed?

Why?  I'm trying to build a CPU out of discrete logic chips, [similar to what is described here,](http://www.scribd.com/doc/71888945/SAP-2-ARCHITECTURE) the SAP-2 Simple-As-Possible Computer.  The SAP-2 can only do Rotate-Left/Right and ignores the carry.  I want to add some functions that utilize the carry flag, but don't want to over complicate the design.

I have a circuit that can Shift Left/Right with carry but doing a Rotate All with carry is proving difficult to implement, and having both functions would be even more complicated.  Here is how it works right now:

If the accumulator contains CY=1  A=0111 0100

then Rotate Left with Carry=

CY=**0** A=1110 100 **0**

or Rotate Right with Carry=

CY=**0** A=**0** 011 1010

Thank-you in advance for your input.